# Ajax call is not going to view function django

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

Hi I am sending request to a django view but its not accessing  view function . Both are in same app . And I am using debugging tool so I tried to debug but on my view no call is received and 
My ajax call code is like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/edit_profile/',
    type: 'get', // This is the default though, you don't actually need to always mention it
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function(data) { 
        alert('Got an error dude');
    }
});
```

**url.py**

```
path('edit_profile/', views.edit_profile , name="edit_profile"),
```

**view.py**

```
def edit_profile(request):
       print(request)   
       print(request)     
    if request.method == 'POST':
       return render(request, 'authenticate/edit_profile.html', context)
```

I am debugging but call is not received in this view function .

Comment: Have you already checked the ajax call in the Chrome Devtools network panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see live demo here [REPL](https://repl.it/repls/JollyDependableBoolean)

First do this if you don't want that your view check the csrf token. This can be done by using decorator @csrf_exempt.

**view.py**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def edit_profile(request):
    print(request)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'authenticate/edit_profile.html')
```

**url.py**

```
path('edit_profile/', views.edit_profile , name="edit_profile"),
```

**ajax request**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/edit_profile/',
    type: 'GET',// This is the default though, you don't actually need to always mention it
    data:{},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function(data) { 
        alert('Got an error dude');
    }
});
```

Comment: Just csrf token  ?

Comment: Yes I think so :) @gamer

Comment: Thanks .Mean to say if I am using Ajax either POST or GET I need to use csrf token exampt .

Comment: You can use this way also you can use csrf token that will prevent you from CSRF attacks. :)