# Ajax call not calling view function in Django

Tags: python, jquery, html, django, ajax

I am trying to build a login form in Django, and when the user hits login, I wish to send the username and password to check which type of user it is as my system has 3 different kinds of users.

Following is the code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt, csrf_protect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



def index(request):
    return render(request, "login.html")


@csrf_protect
def auth_login(request):
    print("Hello !")
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    group = User.objects.get(username=username).groups.values()[0]['name']
    print(username)
    print(user)
    print(password)
    return render(request, "add_form.html")


@csrf_protect
def logout(request):
    logout(request)
```

login.html - (I have a simple bootstrap login form)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Login</title>

<style>
        html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: white;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="text"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body class="text-center">
   <form class="form-signin" id="login-form">{% csrf_token %}
      <img class="mb-4" src="{% static "download.png" %}" alt="Logo"  align="center" height="112" width="112">
      <h1 class="h3 mb-4 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="uname" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
      <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="passwd" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
      <div class="checkbox mb-4">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="loginbutton" type="submit">Sign in</button>

      <p class="mt-3 mb-5 text-muted">Planning Tool</p>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#login-form").on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            login();
        });

    function login(){
        alert($("#uname").val())
          $.ajax({
                url: {% url 'auth:Login' %},
                method : "POST",
                data : {
                    "username" : $("#uname").val(),
                    "password" : $("#passwd").val(),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken' :  "{{ csrf_token }}"
                },
              success : function (data) {
                  alert("successful")
              },
              failure : function (data) {
                  alert("did not pass")
              }
            });
    }

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings

app_name = 'auth'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.index, name='Home'),
    path('auth-login/', views.auth_login, name='Login'),
    path('auth-logout/', views.logout, name='Logout'),
]
```

---- Django console ----

```
(venv) C:\Users\Krushika.Tapedia\PycharmProjects\schedulingtool>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 26, 2019 - 11:50:45
Django version 2.2.4, using settings 'schedulingtool.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[26/Nov/2019 11:50:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3825
[26/Nov/2019 11:50:48] "GET /static/download.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[26/Nov/2019 11:51:00] "POST /auth-login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3825
```

I have referred different answers on the forum, I have tried with this also [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768156/ajax-call-is-not-going-to-view-function-django)

but it does not enter into the function and print the first statement on the terminal.
I am unable to debug this and not able to understand the problem here.

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT : Pasting the whole HTML File for you to try and also the Django console*

Comment: Your `url` in the js script uses `auth:Login` while the `django` uses the path `auth-login`. Also you may use the developer console for debugging `js`.

Comment: On the developer console for js when I use `{% url  'auth:Login' %}` (`auth` is the app name and `Login` is the name of the path) it renders as `'/auth-login/' `

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't see `app_name`. Do you see any errors in the browser?

Comment: No, sadly, I see no errors :(

Comment: Does the post request get received at the server?

Comment: Yes it does, and the ajax call gives me a success alert as well.
I have just added the whole HTML file for you to see this. I have been using ajax calls many times, but never seen this problem, is it with csrf_toke, I have always used `@csrf_exempt` so never had any problem, this time since it was a login session, I decided to use the csrf token

Comment: since you are passing csrf token, you ideally don't need to apply the decorator. Django post requests in version > 2.2 are protected by csrf. Currently, I too am unable to figure out your issue, maybe it's got to do something with a trailing backslash somewhere. I'm working on it and will let you know when I solve it.

Comment: Your bottle neck is the `form` element in `login.html`. You need to add `method=POST` to your `form` and the rest of the code should work fine. The reason behind this could be that this element defaults to the `get` method unless specified but you said it was still sending a `post` request to the server, which is tough to swallow. Anyways, try and tell if this works out.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried removing the decorator as well, but it still doesn't work.If not this I am open to trying an alternative way to get the username and password in the views function and manipulate with it then.

Comment: @Abhyudai in form element adding `method='post'` also doesn't work !! :(

Comment: is this your complete `views` and `urls` `file`? Are you sure that no other function inside it is superseding the corresponding function?

Comment: @Abhyudai just updated with the complete views.py file, the other files ie., the urls.py, and login.html are the complete files

Comment: You have used `url(r'^', views.index, name='Home'),)` just update this to `path(r'^', views.index, name='Home')` in your `urls.py`. This was really hard to figure out. Probably a typo.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you soooo much, yes it worked, I had copied that from previous files and edited it, that's why. I was going crazy not understanding what was the mistake, thanks a ton once again !

Comment: Also, a word of advice would be to not send passwords in raw form. You should probably use some sort of `hash function` before sending it to the server.

Comment: yes yes, Noted !! Thank you :)

Comment: @Abhyudai Can you take a look at this please and let me know your thoughts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59254748/django-save-changes-made-to-model-objects-and-render-when-published

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to change this inside the file `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^', views.index, name='Home'),
```

to

```
path(r'^', views.index, name='Home'),
```

From the official documentation regarding the `url` function

> This function is an alias to **django.urls.re_path()**. It’s likely to be deprecated in a future release.

Your `url` function matches any string and hence all requests are sent to the `index` function inside your `views.py` file.