# Django - save changes made to model objects and render when published

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am new to Django and working on my first project in Django. I am providing a simpler example for my application where - 
I have 3 different types of users for the application.

1. Teacher's Assistant - Schedules/plans the timetable and courses for the teacher depending on day's agenda
2. Teacher - approves the items on the agenda and marks if an item on the schedule is completed
3. Student - views the schedule of an individual teacher

Currently, I have this whole application ready with all its functionalities, where the assistant would create a timetable/schedule (ie., add/edit/delete various model objects which are subjects) for the teacher depending upon her courses and agenda for the class.

Currently, when the assistant, makes changes to the schedule (such as deletes, or edits an existing model object) these changes directly update the model object.

What I would want to achieve is that, only when the Assistant publishes the schedule, the teacher can approve and students should be able to view it, and the assistant should have his own version of the schedule where he can make changes and edits to it (These changes and edits should not be viewed by other two roles unless they are published).
Currently, all the changes made by the Assistant are directly updated in the model objects and the same are rendered onto the pages of the Teacher and Student. I have only one model class for storing the information about the item being scheduled.

How can I design this? Any suggestions/documentation or piece of code would really help.

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1 :
The only solution comes to my mind is when the Assistant hits the publish button, storing a copy of the model objects and rendering this copy onto the pages of other users? But how do I write this in Django?

Comment: One option could be to make two separate models -`AssistantSchedule` and `TeacherSchedule` with similar structure

Comment: If I understood your question well, you may use a `boolean` field `publish` in the schedule model, which may be approved as per your use and filter only schedules that have `publish=True` in your views when showing them to students.

Comment: @Abhyudai yes this actually makes sense, I was trying to think of an elegant way to avoid duplication of the same model. I am going to try implementing this real quick and see it's working. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Thanks, @bhaskarc I am trying to see a way to eliminate soo much of duplication

Comment: @Abhyudai Let's consider a scenario --- where the value `isPublished = False`of a model object is set False by default. When the Assistant hits Publish button, I change the values of `isPublished=True` these models' objects are now being rendered to the Teacher and Student, but what if after rendering, the Assistant decides to make changes to it, and then do I again set it to `False` , and if I do, then the teacher & Student will not be able to see the event which has been published before??

Comment: @KrushikaTapedia so, what do you exactlly need?

Comment: @KrushikaTapedia I don't think we're allowed long discussions here. If you're comfortable we may use google hangout or linkedin

Comment: Yes LinkedIn would be great www.linkedin.com/in/krushika29 We can connect here @Abhyudai

Answer (score 1):

Add two extra variables (created_at and publish_flag) in the model. In view you will send the publish_tag=true and most recent created_at.